# How to use toggle function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am running into a couple of problems when I try to use JavaScript to toggle between classes on click.

What is going on.. Also when I run it on my localhost it runs but only on the first link. not on the second. I tried recreating the same problem but here it becomes even more a mess..

Now for some reason if I use this code even in the snippet, when you click the event happends, then dissapears completely.

```js
var pill = document.querySelector(".navpill");
var sub = document.querySelector(".submenu");

pill.onclick = () => {
    sub.classList.toggle("collapse");
}
```

```css
.mainmenu {
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
}
.navpill {
  padding: 15px;
}
.navpill a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
.submenu {
  display: none;
}
.submenu.collapse {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="mainmenu">
    <li class="navpill"><a href="">Link collapse 1</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li class="navpill"><a href="">sub Link 1</a></li>
            <li class="navpill"><a href="">sub Link 1</a></li>
            <li class="navpill"><a href="">sub Link 1</a></li>
            <li class="navpill"><a href="">sub Link 1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="navpill"><a href="">Link collapse 2</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li class="navpill"><a href="">sub Link 1</a></li>
            <li class="navpill"><a href="">sub Link 1</a></li>
            <li class="navpill"><a href="">sub Link 1</a></li>
            <li class="navpill"><a href="">sub Link 1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="navpill"><a href="">no link</a></li>
    <li class="navpill"><a href="">no link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`href=""` makes it try to navigate to another page. Either try `href="#"` or just don't user hyperlinks if they're not actually intended to be real links. `<li class="navpill">sub Link 1</li>` ought to be just fine for you I'd expect.

Also, `querySelector` only selects the first element in the selected set. So it only acts on your first link. You need to use `querySelectorAll`, loop through the results and add a click to each.

Identifying the specific sublink to act on needs to be done within the click callback, so you can find the one within the menu item which has just been clicked. Also you can't use `navpill` as the class selector for handling the expand/collapse clicks, as it'll crash if you click on one of the sublinks with that class. So I added a new class for the outer, clickable items.

Demo:

```js
var pills = document.querySelectorAll(".expand");

pills.forEach(function(pill) {
  pill.onclick = () => {
    var sub = pill.querySelector(".submenu");
    sub.classList.toggle("collapse");
  }
});
```

```css
.mainmenu {
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
}

.navpill {
  padding: 15px;
  color: white;
}

.submenu {
  display: none;
}

.submenu.collapse {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="mainmenu">
    <li class="navpill expand">Link collapse 1
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li class="navpill">sub Link 1</li>
        <li class="navpill">sub Link 1</li>
        <li class="navpill">sub Link 1</li>
        <li class="navpill">sub Link 1</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="navpill expand">Link collapse 2
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li class="navpill">sub Link 1</li>
        <li class="navpill">sub Link 1</li>
        <li class="navpill">sub Link 1</li>
        <li class="navpill">sub Link 1</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="navpill">no link</li>
    <li class="navpill">no link</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: He Thanks for the answer. Worked great. however i run into the next problem. wich is i need to change more then just 1 variable. In your code that doesnt seem to work. ( or i dont know how )

Comment: Sorry but I'm not really sure what you mean? Your code doesn't have any variables. Anyway...I answered the question as it was given. I think you should accept the answer. if you have a new and different problem, you should ask a new and different question about it :-)

Comment: I mean i have another class to add to a different object ( class ). You can see in the snippet. It shows the menu, and changes the background color of the UL. in your code it only toggles the submenu.

Comment: You only inserted that after I wrote the answer. If you change the question substantially after people have written answers, that's not really on. People put time and effort into answering. In return they expect the odd upvote and accepted answer. They _don't_ expect to spend their evening changing the answer because the person asking decided to move the goalposts after the fact. Revert your changes and accept this answer please. Like I said, if you have a new requirement or a new problem, you can ask a new question about it. Put a link to it here, and I might just take a look. Thanks.

Comment: (For reference, https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66016490/revisions shows what time you added your new parts to the question, compared with when I - and others - wrote answers to your original question. If your original question didn't reflect your real situation...well that's not our fault.)

Comment: Oke. i tought i would change my question so i dont have to keep making new posts.. But i guess thats not how it works. If you want i can make a new post..?!

Comment: It's up to you. If you want that part of your problem answered, you should make a new post.

Comment: `i tought i would change my question so i dont have to keep making new posts`...no that's really not how it works. Think about it...any change you make (other than just to alter the formatting or add more info about the _same_ problem) means that any previous answers then make no sense. So it's not useful for anyone reading, and it's not fair on those who answered previously.

Comment: He thanks for re-rolling the question. I was trying to find how to do that. Well anyway i gave you the answer and voted you up. Sorry for changing my question.

Comment: No problem. We all have to learn. Feel free to add a link to your next question here, I will be sure to take a look when I have a moment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66018703/toggle-menu-with-javascript-target-multiple-variables-with-1-click-function Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

By using the same class for all of your nav, both main and sub you will need to change how you are calling your nav.

using QuerySelectorALL and `>` you can get just the main nav. Then using `nextElementSibling` you can get the next navigation.

I'm also looking for an already open menu and hiding it.

```js
var pills = document.querySelectorAll(".mainmenu > .navpill");

pills.forEach((pill) => {
  pill.onclick = (e) => {
    sub = e.target.nextElementSibling;
    open = document.querySelector(".submenu.collapse")
    if(open) open.classList.remove("collapse");
    if(sub) sub.classList.toggle("collapse");
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```css
.mainmenu {
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
}

.navpill {
  padding: 15px;
}

.navpill a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.submenu {
  display: none;
}

.submenu.collapse {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="mainmenu">
    <li class="navpill"><a href="">Link collapse 1</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li class="navpill"><a href="">sub Link 1</a></li>
        <li class="navpill"><a href="">sub Link 1</a></li>
        <li class="navpill"><a href="">sub Link 1</a></li>
        <li class="navpill"><a href="">sub Link 1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="navpill"><a href="">Link collapse 2</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li class="navpill"><a href="">sub Link 1</a></li>
        <li class="navpill"><a href="">sub Link 1</a></li>
        <li class="navpill"><a href="">sub Link 1</a></li>
        <li class="navpill"><a href="">sub Link 1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="navpill"><a href="">no link</a></li>
    <li class="navpill"><a href="">no link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**querySelector** selects just one element.  Use **querySelectorAll**.

Then to limit the submenu items affected to just the ones under their parent menu item, query from that `element` as opposed to from the `document`.  You'll also want to limit `querySelectorAll` to just choose elements with the `navpill` class *which are direct children of* the `mainmenu` class (done using the `>` symbol between selectors).

```js
let pill = document.querySelectorAll(".mainmenu > .navpill");

pill.forEach ((element) => {
  let sub = element.querySelector(".submenu");
  let mainItem = element.firstChild;
  /* if you want your menu to collapse when clicking a submenu item
   * remove the line above, and on the line below, replace "mainItem"
   * with "element". */
  mainItem.onclick = (e) => {
    if (sub){
      sub.classList.toggle("collapse");
    }
  }
});
```

**Note:** Because your submenu items are encompassed in / children of your main menu items (per the selectors originally chosen), clicking on a submenu item will also set off the click event handler for the main menu item above it (the `<li>`).  If each submenu item has a link, you'll likely not care - but clicking on a submenu item will also collapse the submenu. The comment in the code above explains how to obtain either behavior, defaulting with the option of leaving the submenu open unless explicitly closed by again clicking on the main menu item.

As far as the difference between `href="#"` vs `href=""`, as others suggested, you can use `<a>` for your main menu items which are themselves links, and use something else, for example, `<span>` to hold your main menu items meant to open a submenu.  That way, you don't send users to the top of your page any time they click a main menu item (using `href="#"`). You can then change your css for main item entries to the following, so that you get the same cursor behavior for both `<a>` and `<span>`:

```css
.navpill span, .navpill a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

That's a quite understandable way to handle it.  In the case, for example, another developer has to one day edit the site, they'd quickly understand your intentions and not get tripped up in `e.preventDefault` or other relatively obscure code.